Does Bayesian regard samples as fixed?
A video on confidence intervals from zedstatistics said sample is fixed from Bayesian viewpoint.  But I doubt if this statement is true since it is not possible to construct the posterior probability $P(\theta | X=x)$ if $X$ is not considered as r.v. An extract of such discussion in the video is attached below for reference:

Edits:
I revised to $P(\theta | X=x)$ to avoid confusion.

I think X would be considered an observed random variable.  Its sensible to think of $X$ as coming from distribution, but once conditioned on $X$ is considered as fixed

Random variables are a frequentist concept. For a Bayesian, the data are fixed. Everything else is a probability distribution.

The frequentist column shows 7 CIs from 7 samples (each one fixed). It would be more accurate to have said ""sampling is random". Helpful notatation is to use X for rv and x for a specific sample outcome. Bayesian calculations are usually conditioned on x.

It is more sensible to state that Bayesian analysis is conditional on the observed sample, which is indeed one (or several) realisation of a random variable whose distribution is used in the construction of the posterior distribution. Credible interval properties are thus conditional on that realised sample.

@RomkeBontekoe Can you show me how $X$ is not random variable or any references on that? When you say data are fixed, I guess you mean observed data are fixed.  But don’t frequentist and bayesian both agree that observed data are fixed?

Random variables are necessary to construct models. If you just consider data as "fixed", a lot of modeling becomes impossible. It becomes impossible to treat measurement errors ... endogeneity becomes impossible, as correlation between x and the error terms cannot be spoken off ...

Perhaps you benefit from having a peek at my tutorial. You can read most of it online under "Read Sample."
Amazon

A lot of the confusion has to do with the forced adoption of frequentist terminology for Bayesian ideas, in particular here "sample" and "parameter". From a purely Bayesian perspective, the distinction is between "knowns" and "unknowns": the latter have an associated probability to describe our uncertainty regarding their true™ value, the former don't. McElreath recently gave a talk about this.
